# How many devices can be connected to one wire bus

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, sensors, temperature, bus

How many devices can be connected to one wire bus and how many temperature sensors(DS18B20) can be connected to Raspberry Pi 3b+?

Comment: The DS18B20 is a one-wire device. IIRC one-wire is not really a bus, but rather a point-to-point connection. Therefore you can theoretically connect as many as you have GPIO pins (28 on the Pi3b)

Comment: You can connect at least 20, and if you use buffers, 30 or more: 

(1) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98394/raspberry-pi-3b-do-not-detect-ds18b20-on-1wire/98434#98434

(2) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100203/ds18b20-temperature-sensor-rpi-3-4-driver-wiring-detection-and-python-progr/100244#100244

(3) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/111412/rpi3b-python-ds2482-i2c-to-1-wire-bridge-connecting-10-ds18b20-temperature-sen/111421#111421

Comment: @PMF That's so wrong on ANY level, hope nobody comes by and takes that for real... (1-Wire IS a bus, there is exactly ONE GPIO for One-Wire - And theoretically it can support hundreds of devices, in this case just limited by the RP itself, not the bus)